# How to set custom post type field as post title to avoid 'Auto Draft'

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am using the Advanced custom fields plugin and Custom post type UI to give my users some extra functionality. The problem I have is that I have setup a users information menu and in the list view all new posts appear as Auto Draft. Is there anyway I can make the field slug company name act as the post title for the list view?.

I tried the below code but it is not updating the company name as post title and in the custom post page it display message like **"You are currently editing the page that shows your latest posts."**

**My Sample code:**

```
add_filter('title_save_pre', 'save_title');
function save_title() {
        if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'users') : // my custom post type name
          $new_title = $_POST['company_name']; // my custom field name
          $my_post_title = $new_title;
        endif;
        return $my_post_title;
}
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54711/title-save-pre-on-post-publish

Comment: Have you looked at this? [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/custom-post-type-with-custom-title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/custom-post-type-with-custom-title) That should work.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'save_post_handler' , 20 );
function save_post_handler( $post_id ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'users' ) {
        $title              = get_field( 'company_name', $post_id ); 
        $data['post_title'] = $title;
        $data['post_name']  = sanitize_title( $title );
        wp_update_post( $data );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use name="post_title" in your input**.

```
<input type="text" name="post_title" id="meta-text" class="form-control" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I literally just read the php website top to bottom yesterday, but I read a few posts about trying to do this and assembled this solution that is working for me. I have a custom post type called artists, I combine the artist acf field of first_name and last_name and set that as the title. For your example you could remove the parts that add last name.

```
// Auto-populate artist post type title with ACF first name last name.
function nd_update_postdata( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
// If this isn't an 'artists' post type, don't update it.
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'artists' ) {   
    $first_name = get_field('first_name', $post_id);
    $last_name = get_field('last_name', $post_id);
    $title = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
    $slug = sanitize_title( $title );
    $postdata = array(
         'ID'      => $post_id,
         'post_title'  => $title,
         'post_type'   => 'artists',
         'post_name'   => $slug
    );
wp_update_post( $postdata, true );
return $value;
}
}
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=first_name', 'nd_update_postdata', 
10, 3);
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=last_name', 'nd_update_postdata', 10, 
3);
```